# Как блокировать плохих ботов на VPS Apache

Tags: apache, сервер

у меня есть список ботов, которых я хочу заблокировать, чтобы они зря не нагружали VPS, на которой более 100 сайтов.

в `.htaccess` для каждого сайта добавлять не хочу команды, потому что сайтов много.

Я слышал, что есть файл `"httpd.conf"` для конфигурации `Apache`. Но так как опыта мало, хочу спросить, какую директиву туда написать для блокировки бота?

Список ботов выглядит так:

`LinkpadBot`, `Sosospider`, `Sogou web spider`, `aesop_com_spiderman`, `SemrushBot`, `backweb`, `batchftp`, `black.hole`, `blackwidow`, `blowfish`, `botalot`, `buddy`, `builtbottough` ....тут еще 200 штук

Comment: А что бы вы написали в htaccess ? вот то же самое пишется и в httpd.conf. В зависимости от выбранного способа блокировки и выбранной директивы определяется блок конфига, в котором это допустимо писать (это смотрится в документации на апач в описании директивы)

Comment: В .htaccess я бы написал так: 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SemrushBot [OR]
 Тут ещё 200 строчек таких же 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AhrefsBot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]